# MySQL SELECT Substring of rows that do not exist from other TABLE

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am sure this has been answered before, but I am just learning mysql and so I do not know how to properly search for the solution.  I have two tables:

```
Table1                  Table2
id email                id  domain
-- ----                 --  ----
1  name@domain1.com     1   domain1.com
2  name@domain2.com     2   domain4.com
3  name@domain3.com
4  name@domain4.com
```

Using the emails in Table1, I would like to return the domains that do not exist in table2, and then write them to Table2, so I have a complete, unique list of domains in Table 2.

```
Table1                  Table2
id email                id  domain
-- ----                 --  ----
1  name@domain1.com     1   domain1.com
2  name@domain2.com     2   domain4.com
3  name@domain3.com     3   domain2.com
4  name@domain4.com     4   domain3.com
```

Comment: make the domain names a unique key in table2 then INSERT IGNORE select distinct substring() etc from table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `WHERE NOT IN` with a sub query

```
INSERT INTO Table2 ( domain )
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1)
FROM Table1  
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1) NOT IN (SELECT domain FROM Table2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @TechTuned Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

make the domain names a unique key in table2 then INSERT IGNORE select distinct substring() etc from table1

```
Alter table_2 
 add unique key k1(domain);

insert ignore into table_2(domain)
select distinct substring_index(email,'@',-1)
from table_1;
```

Where IGNORE will err ignore errors like duplicates.